# Sync iPhone Music with Rythmbox or Banshee

Tags: sync, rhythmbox, banshee, iphone

When I sync my iPhone 5s, it shows it has successfully synced in the program, but when I disconnect the device, the content does not show in my music.

The software appear to sync fine and finish successfully. The music appears on the software. The iPhone however does not show my music after the sync. When I re-plug my device, the software cease to show the music as well. My storage usage on my iPhone does go up, so it seems to have actually copied the files.

How do I get my iPhone to detect my synced music?